# How to update the data in mongodb by id in my case?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am sending an object to the php file, I need to save it in MongoDB with a special id which is sent by AJAX

here is the code:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();
$editor = $db->editor;
$editor->update(
     array( '_id' => $_GET['id'] ),
     array( '$set' => json_decode($_POST['data']) )
);
```

but this code doesn't work

I have looked through a lot of questions familiar to my one here on stackoverflow

so, I really need help, because I can't get it!

thanks =)

Comment: Despite being extremely insecure how does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Because the _id at mongo is not a simple string but a Object.**

you can get this conclusion by **try mongo under command line**.

example: db.test.findOne({});

```
$editor->update(
    array( 
        '_id' => new MongoId($_GET['id']) 
    ),
     array( 
         '$set' => json_decode($_POST['data']
    ) 
);
```

More [PHP MongoClass ID](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php)

Comment: I tried to solve this problem in the same way, but I always get 500 error

Comment: oh, The seconde line at your code should be  **$editor = $mongo->editor;** 500? you can open the php error_reporting to get more message.:D

Comment: There is any systax error or other? Try debug to find it.